# How can I get dropdownlist value when checkbox is checked in MVC using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.Net MVC and JQuery.

I want to get row detail including selected dropdownlist value placed in one column.I want to store value in one object like customer = {customerId :'',customerName:''}

so How can I do this using JQuery.

here is my table structure.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;" class="data-display-table" id="tblFleet">           
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chk-@item.Data"  />
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @item.CustomerId
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.CustomerName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.ContactNo
                        </td>                        
                        <td>
                            @{string ddlId = "ddl" + item.CustomerId}

                            @Html.DropDownList(ddlId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MessageTemplateList, new { @style = "width:140px" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure if you use @Html.CheckBoxFor, it will automatically understand whether or not the checkbox is ticked or not.

For instance if you use a with the input tags (input type="submit")

Which posts back to the controller, as long as you pass in the model (which is what I assume you're doing since you would use CheckBoxFor), ASP should understand if its checked

Answer (score 0):

Try this : bind change event for checkbox and then find its parent `tr` and then find `select` box inside parent `tr`.

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')
     {
       var parentTR = $(this).closest('tr');
       var selectBox = $(parentTR).find('select');
       var selectBoxValue = $(selectBox).val();
       alert(selectBoxValue);
     }
  });
});
```

**Note** - I am reading select box value when checkbox is selected, you can remove if condition if this is not your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      var customerid =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
      var drop =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(4).find('select option:selected').val();
    }
  });
});
```